# Process bibitem without year data in an elsarticle-harv reference list

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, elsarticle, bst

I am preparing a draft required to have Elsevier's **reference list style** (i.e. the style of the bibliography list) and I've chosen `elsarticle-harv` reference style because it's the closest to my requirements.

However, some online items don't tell people when they went online, so there are bibitems don't have "year" keys. In the reference list, these items will leave spaces in the "year" field and cause a comma immediately followed by a period.

(**UPDATE**: Let's discuss the *reference style* only, not the citation style. I understand that a bibitem without year won't give a proper "author+year" in-text citation, but that's another question. Now my concern is just about the format of the reference list.)

Please see my MWE (compiled by pdflatex+bibtex):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
@misc{miscwebsite,
    author = {{Author 1}},
    title = {{Misc Website}},
    url = {http://foo.bar/},
    note = {Accessed 31.01.2000.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Here I cite a webpage without year \citep{miscwebsite}.
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot. The comma before the empty year field should be removed.

[image]

---

I have tried following methods, but none works:

- Using `elsarticle` documentclass instead of `article`
- Adding an empty year key into the bibitem, i.e. `year={}`
- Applying `@online` item type (though I think it's for BibLaTeX) instead of `@misc`

I guess I might need to customize the `elsarticle-harv.bst` file or something even more complicated, but I haven't done such things before.

Any help or information will be appreciated.

Comment: @Mico That word doesn't seem to be magical. It will literally print "n.d." in both citation text and the reference list.